# Values assigned to char in c++

Tags: c++, char, character, ascii, single-quotes

`char b = 'ABC DEF';` I know this is wrong but

`char a = '(xx)';` where xx is a two digit number, why is this not wrong?

where `cout << a;` prints `)` whatever the number is.

Comment: Multi-char literals are *implementation defined*. What probably happens is that `'(xx)` is stored as an `int` (which is usually four bytes and therefore fits four one-byte characters) and the compiler simply truncates the upper bits and just assigns the low byte to the variable.

Comment: Nice dupe find.